# Correct Value for Nested Fractions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{2}{\frac{1}{y}}=\frac{4}{1}$$

Solve for $y$. I tried this and got $y=2$ but am skeptical of my answer. Is it correct?

Comment: No, I think you are right. Isn't this not the answer?

Comment: I don't have the answers unfortunately, but I just wanted to check. :)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Cheers.

Comment: You can always verify a prospective answer. In this case $\frac2{\frac12}\ \ ?= \ 4$. Two divided by one half is 4, so $y=2$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{y}$. This gives $\frac{2}{y/y}=\frac{4}{y}$ which simplifies to $2=\frac{4}{y}$ which should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach: multiply the numerator and the denominator of $\frac{2}{\frac{1}{y}}$ by $y$ to get $\frac{2y}{1}$ for the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you know whether you are talking about
$$
\frac{\;\;\displaystyle\frac{2}{1}\;\;}{y}
$$
or
$$
\frac{2}{\;\;\displaystyle\frac{1}{y}\;\;}
$$

Answer (score 0):

My preference has always been multiplying by $1$.

$$\frac{2}{\frac{1}{y}} = \frac{\frac{2}{1}}{\frac{1}{y}}\cdot\frac{\frac{y}{1}}{\frac{y}{1}} = \frac{\frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{y}{1}}{\frac{1}{y}\cdot\frac{y}{1}}=\frac{\frac{2y}{1\cdot 1}}{\frac{1\cdot y}{y\cdot 1}}=\frac{\frac{2y}{1}}{\frac{y}{y}}=\frac{2y}{1}=2y$$